# nuget pack task in Azure Dev ops pipeline gives error

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Hi i'm a newbie to azure devops CID and pipelining.
the azure devops is on premise, my pipeline looks as below however it fails at nuget pack command (2nd from bottom)

the error i get is ##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(Error NU5012: Unable to find 'C:\AzureDevOpsAgents\Agent#1_work\4\s\Code\MyCompany.Core\bin\release\net472\MyCompany.Core.dll'. Make sure the project has been built.

I went into the azure agents directory and the dll is located C:\AzureDevOpsAgents\Agent#1_work\4\s\Code\MyCompany.Core\bin\x64\Release\net472\MyCompany.Core.dll

the difference being the x64, so how i can i get nuget pack to take into consideration the architecture as part of the pack path

[image]

variables
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i as usual every time i post a question on here, despite struggling for hours i manage to solve it.

I've added $(BuildPlatform)\  in front of the default $(BuildConfiguration) for the configuration to package and i can see a package in the location

[image]